# How do I export customized Libreoffice config files?

Tags: libreoffice, configuration, customization

Is this possible? I want to make my own config file for my customizations that I can apply whenever I reinstall my system. For example, Ubuntu's default font color is just stupid. I want it to be BLACK and not dark grey. And I want to turn on autosave every 3rd minute and backup files.

Is there a config file that I can change? The `.libreoffice/*` folders and XML files doesn't make sense, and they don't seem to change when I change stuff in LibreOffice. Could someone please help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  11.10, 11.04, 10.10  (in case affects solution)

Comment: Which version of **LibreOffice**?  latest is **3.4.4**

Comment: Yeah, It's Ubuntu 11.10 and LibreOffice 3.4.4.

Comment: I'm still wondering about this, by the way. I want a script that I can use for updating the central config for LibreOffice. Mainly font color and autosave settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer to my own question once again. According to [this](http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/5015/where-is-user-data-stored/) post over at Ask Libreoffice, the config file `~/.config/libreoffice/*/user/registrymodifications.xcu` is the one to look at. It's a huge XML file, which could make it a bit tricky to modify via command line, but if you just create your own `registrymodifications.xcu` right after you install LibreOffice, you can just add your custom options first in an almost empty file as a template, and LibreOffice will append what's missing when you start it.

Remember to start your file with

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oor:items xmlns:oor="http://openoffice.org/2001/registry" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

And end it with

```xml
</oor:items>
```

Anyway, the XML nodes that I wanted to change are these:

### Turn autosave on/off

```xml
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Common/Save/Document">
  <prop oor:name="AutoSave" oor:op="fuse">
    <value>false</value>
  </prop>
</item>
(...)
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Recovery/AutoSave">
  <prop oor:name="Enabled" oor:op="fuse">
    <value>false</value>
  </prop>
</item>
```

Change the `<value>false</value>` to `<value>true</value>` in both places to enable.

### Set autosave interval. Default is 15 minutes.

```xml
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Common/Save/Document">
  <prop oor:name="AutoSaveTimeIntervall" oor:op="fuse">
    <value>15</value>
  </prop>
</item>
(...)
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Recovery/AutoSave">
  <prop oor:name="TimeIntervall" oor:op="fuse">
    <value>15</value>
  </prop>
</item>
```

Change the `<value>15</value>` to `<value>YourInterval</value>` both places.

### Change default text color to BLACK instead of DARK GREY

```xml
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.UI/ColorScheme/ColorSchemes/org.openoffice.Office.UI:ColorScheme['LibreOffice']/FontColor">
  <prop oor:name="Color" oor:op="fuse">
    <value xsi:nil="true"/>
  </prop>
</item>
```

Change the `<value xsi:nil="true"/>` to `<value>0</value>`.

### Turn off auto suggested words (annoying feature, IMO)

```xml
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Writer/AutoFunction/Completion">
  <prop oor:name="Enable" oor:op="fuse">
    <value>true</value>
  </prop>
</item>
```

Change the `<value>true</value>` to `<value>false</value>` to disable.

### Change autosave path to $CONFIGDIR/tmp instead of /tmp

`/tmp` gets purged at reboot, so if your computer crashes or the power goes out, you're not in luck by using the default settings in LO.

```xml
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Paths/Paths/org.openoffice.Office.Paths:NamedPath['Temp']">
    <prop oor:name="WritePath" oor:op="fuse">
        <value>$(user)/tmp/</value>
    </prop>
</item>
```

LibreOffice/OpenOffice creates the directory for you if it doesn't exist. There's already a `$(user)/temp` folder, but no one seems to know what it's for. To be sure, I created a new one just called `tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile

But it does not answer all the questions you have raised ..

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it. It doesn't help me at all and all the config files I can find, are written in hard to read XML.